# Tibco BW6 : External Command - Not getting expected output with Linux command

Tags: linux, tibco, tibco-business-works

In Tibco BW6, I am executing below Linux command using 'External Command' activity. Applicatoin is deployed on Linux server. Provide Command output is checked.

Command  : find /opt/apps/projects/TestApplication/ -name "*.xml" -type f -mtime +180

Working directory : /opt/apps/projects/TestApplication/

Directory TestApplication has 777 permission.

But in the response I am not getting the list of files present at provided location.

The same command is getting executed as expected on server using Putty.

Can you please help me if anything is missed and why I am not getting the list of file in the output ?

Comment: Are you sure there are XML files in that directory tree that are more than 180 days old?  If you skip the `-mtime`, do you see them?

Comment: Yes,,,there are xml file that are 180 days old. And I am getting list of files when executed that command on Linux server.

Comment: try removing the double quotes, or using the option Remove Parameter Quotes, if it doesn't work do a test with a simple file name (like test.xml without quotes) or try a basic command like ls